# Writing mulitple times in a special (given) pipe C++

Tags: c++, windows, pipe, named-pipes

I try to handle some pipes in a CAD Programm with c++.
The programm Geograf has two pipes. They are both in the following path:
\.\pipe\GGPIPE
The interesting on this pipe is, that I have to open a pipe then close a pipe and open a pipe again.
After this steps, I can send commands through the pipe to Geograf.

**My problem or question is,** why I can **write** to pipe the **only one time**?
After I excecute my program the second time, the handle have a INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.

If I want to send a command again, I have to restart the Geograf programm (and with it, the GGPIPE). After a restart I can send only one command throgh the pipe.

When I write to another given pipe in windows, I can write multiple times.

Is there a way to **write multiple times** in the GGPIPE?
Or can i **manipulate a given pipe**?

Comment: You're much more likely to get a fast response from the creators of the software. Maybe you're sending something that horribly offends Geograf's parser and it closes the pipe to reset itself. Can't say. Seeing your code may help, but again if it's a protocol issue and not a matter of string termination or similar you will need someone familiar with the protocol to debug. Perhaps the protocol closes the pipe after every instruction. Sadly my German is weak and I can't find English docs.

Comment: It might also help showing the code used to open and write to the pipe.

Comment: After you start the program the second time, you *do* create a new handle? (I.e. you open the pipe again?)

Comment: Yes i create a new handle