# Is there a way to serialize/deserialize a HANDLE in/from a file?

Tags: c++, file, serialization, pipe, handle

is there a way to serialize a HANDLE in a file?
This is my Handle:

```
hPipeReadOrWrite = CreateFileA(
        TEXT(PIPEPATH), //Pipepath 
        GENERIC_WRITE,                  //Access Mode
        0,                              //ShareMode
        NULL,                           //Security Attributes
        OPEN_EXISTING,                  //Action on a File
        0,                              //Type of File
        NULL);
```

I ask this, because I can only open the pipe once. If I could write the Handle in a file (and dont close the Handle) and deserialize it later, then maybe I´m able to write multiple times in the pipe.
My question before was the following: [Writing mulitple times in a special (given) pipe C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633393/writing-mulitple-times-in-a-special-given-pipe-c)

I already tried the following, but here I have a file_descriptor instead of a File:

```
        if (hPipeWrite != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    int file_descriptor = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)hPipeWrite, 0);

    if (file_descriptor != -1) {
    FILE* file = _fdopen(file_descriptor, "w");

    if (file != NULL) {
    std::ofstream stream(file);

    stream << "Hello World\n";

    // Closes stream, file, file_descriptor, and file_handle.
    stream.close();

    file = NULL;
    file_descriptor = -1;
    hPipeWrite = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Handles are pretty much unique per-process. So if you save it to a file in one process and read it from another process it won't work. It will work if you later read it from the same process that save it, *and* you haven't closed the handle in between. But doing something like that makes no sense, you could just keep the handle in a variable that lasts the lifetime of your process.

Comment: "you could just keep the handle in a variable that lasts the lifetime of your process"
The problem is, that after closing the handle i cant create a handle again until i restart the other programm I want to communicate with. Because of this i thinking about saving Handles....

Comment: Then it might be a bug in the other program, and nothing you can't do but report it to them.

Comment: Mh... yes it would be the best I think... I had success with wirting multiple times with a never ending loop, which waits for userinput of the console, where I send some commands through the pipe. But after i closed the written programm i have to restart the other programm to reach the pipe... But thanks anyway for your time and help

Comment: BUT... isn´t it possible to get an already opened Handle?... Maybe directly from the pipe? https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: You must call DuplicateHandle() to make the handle value valid in another process.  Knowing what process created the handle is crucial of course, you don't necessarily know when you are listening on a pipe and don't know what's on the other end.  So include the required info, the process ID.

Comment: Thanks for the other idea! I'll try it :)